Aggregator Query for complex mongoDB Structure
`I am trying to write an aggregator query for the complex DB document below, ideally i am looking for creating multiple streams from the given activities set, identifying the parent child hierarchy and recursively processing the input document.
Title: Aggregator Query for Identifying Workflow Streams in Hierarchical Document
Body:
I'm trying to write an aggregation query in MongoDB to process a complex document representing a set of activities with parent-child relationships. The goal is to identify multiple workflows (streams) from this data.
Input Document:
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "activities": [
      {
        "activityId": "A1",
        "children": [
          {
            "activityId": "A2"
          },
          {
            "activityId": "A7"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "activityId": "A2",
        "children": [
          {
            "activityId": "A3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "activityId": "A3",
        "children": [
          {
            "activityId": "A4"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "activityId": "A4",
        "children": [
          {
            "activityId": "A5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "activityId": "A4",
        "children": [
          {
            "activityId": "A6"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "activityId": "A6",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "activityId": "A5",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "activityId": "A7",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "activityId": "B1",
        "children": [
          {
            "activityId": "B2"
          },
          {
            "activityId": "B3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "activityId": "B2",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "activityId": "B3",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "activityId": "C1",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "897",
    "activities": [
      {
        "activityId": "X1",
        "children": [
          {
            "activityId": "X2"
          },
          {
            "activityId": "X7"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "activityId": "X2",
        "children": [
          {
            "activityId": "X3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "activityId": "X3",
        "children": [
          {
            "activityId": "X4"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "activityId": "X4",
        "children": [
          {
            "activityId": "X5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "activityId": "X4",
        "children": [
          {
            "activityId": "X6"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "activityId": "X6",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "activityId": "X5",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "activityId": "X7",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "activityId": "Y1",
        "children": [
          {
            "activityId": "Y2"
          },
          {
            "activityId": "Y3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "activityId": "Y2",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "activityId": "Y3",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "activityId": "Z1",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]

** Aggregator query: **
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "activities.children": []
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": "$activities.activityId",
      "connectFromField": "activities.activityId",
      "connectToField": "activities.children.activityId",
      "as": "workflowStreams"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "workflowStreams": {
        "$setUnion": [
          [
            "$activities.activityId"
          ],
          "$workflowStreams.activities.activityId"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "workflowStreams": {
        "$push": "$workflowStreams"
      }
    }
  }
])


** Expected Response **
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "workflowStreams": [
      [
        "A1",
        "A2",
        "A3",
        "A4",
        "A6"
      ],
      [
        "A1",
        "A2",
        "A3",
        "A4",
        "A5"
      ],
      [
        "A1",
        "A7"
      ],
      [
        "B1",
        "B2"
      ],
      [
        "B1",
        "B3"
      ],
      [
        "C1"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "897",
    "workflowStreams": [
      [
        "X1",
        "X2",
        "X3",
        "X4",
        "X6"
      ],
      [
        "X1",
        "X2",
        "X3",
        "X4",
        "X5"
      ],
      [
        "X1",
        "X7"
      ],
      [
        "Y1",
        "Y2"
      ],
      [
        "Y1",
        "Y3"
      ],
      [
        "Z1"
      ]
    ]
  }
]


Please edit your question to remove the double-paste. You have put the Input, Aggregation, and Expected twice. Is your field called activiies or activities ?

Consider refactoring your schema to store activities as individual documents if you are performing a lot of operations on the level of activities. Currently, you are prone to a potential 16MB single document size limit breach, various performance issues and query complexity.

You might be able to use $graphLookup if you can separate the data into 2 collections

The most seamless way to reuse the solution from your previous question I can think of is to create a database view to "flatten" the activities entries into individual documents. You can then perform the same query as before.
db.runCommand( { create: "activityView", viewOn: "streams", pipeline: [
    {
        $match: {
            // put your criteria here
            id: "123"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$activities"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$activities"
          }
    }
]} )

Then, you can reuse the same solution on the view.
db.activityView.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "children": []
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": "$activityId",
      "connectFromField": "activityId",
      "connectToField": "children.activityId",
      "as": "workflowStreams"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "workflowStreams": {
        "$setUnion": [
          [
            "$activityId"
          ],
          "$workflowStreams.activityId"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "",
      "workflowStreams": {
        "$push": "$workflowStreams"
      }
    }
  }
])


I would like to reemphasize the importance of refactoring your schema as in the comments. Currently, you are prone to a potential 16MB single document size limit breach, various performance issues and query complexity.

This query should produce a response similar to the one expected:
db.collection.aggregate([ 
  { 
    $unwind: "$activities" 
  }, 
  { 
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$activities.activityId",
      connectFromField: "activities.activityId",
      connectToField: "activities.children.activityId",
      as: "workflowStream",
      restrictSearchWithMatch: { "id": "$id" }  
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    $set: {
      workflowStream: {
        $setUnion: [ ["$activities.activityId"], "$workflowStream.activities.activityId" ]
      }
    }
  }, 
  { 
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      workflowStreams: {
        $addToSet: "$workflowStream"
      }
    }
  }
])

